# VS 2008-- one web project, one class library project. Each referencing a third CL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference, class-library

I have a VS2008 solution with two projects in it.  One is a web project, the other a class library project.  The web project has a reference to the class library project's generated assembly.

Each project in turn references an assembly (call it "mydll") that's built from a class library project located in another VS solution.

If I were to copy mydll to separate directories and tell the web and class library projects to use those separate directories, what happens when I build my web project; which "copy" of mydll goes into the web bin folder?

And if the versions of mydll are different in the two directories, which one ends up in my web's bin folder after a rebuild?  (Assume there are no strongly named assemblies involved here.)

I hope my question makes sense, if not let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice question to make me think.

Answer (score 1):

In either case, the DLL referenced by your web project will end up in your web's `bin` folder.

Now, common sense will lead you to use *exactly* the same source assembly (compiled DLL) to reference from both projects in your solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The dll will be copied from the directory that is referenced by your web project.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If dll filenames are the same, last one in wins, which would be your web project since the web project depends on the class dll.

If filenames are different, both.